# Can I get a downloaded file outside a WP7 device?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

It seems that all wp7 apps have sandboxing. My app downloads an MP3, can I at least sync it with Zune or somehow save it to PC?

Comment: Usually there are some resource space that are universally accesable like the pictures, music that can be access by any app. might try to save the mp3 there sow you can access it with Zune. Just an idea. I haven't program in windows mobile for some time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current version of WP7 you cannot save songs to the media library.

You can save them to IsolatedStorage, but since your goal is to transfer them off the device, your only option is to upload them to a web service. From there you can then transfer the files to a PC etc.

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Microsoft Silverlight

Answer (score 1):

Anything that you download can be saved to isolated storage, but that is unique to your application, is not synched with Zune, and cannot be accessed by other applications. You could take a look at this approach for [desktop communication](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173829/Windows-Phone-7-How-to-Communicate-with-a-Desktop-.aspx), but then you'd need to provide a desktop application. In which case, you might just as well download the MP3 on the desktop and let Zune sync it with your WP7 normally. If you're provided something more than just media playback, then you can just access the phone's media library from your app.

Comment: Here's hoping they add some sort of support for this soon, I have a ton of PDF's on my HD7 that I can't backup or at least copy to my PC.

Comment: Could you use a DropBox client to transfer them to DropBox?